# Extracting points as CSV from count polygon

Tags: qgis

By using "points count polygon" I found the number of points in every polygon. I have to extract those points to a CSV file but I can't.

[image: point_number_in_polygons]

I came to know that I have 957 points in my 1st polygon (as shown in figure attached) now I need those 957 points to be extracted as CSV file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click with the selection tool on your polygon.
Then open via the Processing Toolbox the tool "Select by Location".
Select the Point Layer and your polygon layer with the selected polygon(s). Tick the Box "are within" and "Selected Features only" (this box you find under the drop down menu where you can select the polygon layer).

This will select all Points which are within your selected polygon. With the selection acitve, right click on your Point Layer in the Layer overview -> Export -> save selected features As

Here you can Pick .CSV as format and your desired location where to save the CSV file to.

Comment: You can skip a step by using the `export by location` tool with the same settings as `select by location`.